# What android form controller to use for selection of large range of numbers

Tags: android

I'm working on a application for tracking body mass measurements. I need the user to be able to input a number representing body weight, whose magnitude ranges from 0.00 kg to normally 300.00 kg. The precision of body weight is two decimals when weight is below 10 kg (50 gram, mainly for babies) and one decimal (100 gram) for adults. Total range of numbers is 3900.

The variation between measurements is expected to be of maximum +-2 kg, but dependent on frequency of measurement it could be higher as well.

I have been using a simple text entry field with data verification, but have noticed that it is by far the slowest portion of filling out the form.

Any help in picking what would be best suitable form controller would be greatly appreciated. I just want the user to have the best experience in quickly and precisely picking from a large range of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented an custom view which is a circular seek bar. The seek bar is used for precisely pick of values while the +/- buttons change the value in larger intervals. It works pretty well. You can find the source code here: https://github.com/ismarslomic/CircularSeekBar

[image: Clock Slider example]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a normal number picker widget, but remember what the user last picked so he/she only has to add/subtract a small number by clicking the +/- once or twice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried the NumberPicker right now. It could actually work, but Im concerned about the performance. It took 1507 milliseconds for the setDisplayedValues(String[3900]) method to complete, which is the only way to set the decimal values in picker (it only support int as default)...

Answer (score 1):

Go for a custom view. Read this

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how should the custom view look like. The link you pasted is only about how to create the custom view, but not what view should fit for my purpose.

Comment: There are 3900 possible values at least so I would suggest a view like andoird contacts app listview. It shows a alphabet at one end for quicker movement.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such widget and I think that you need to create your own one to get the best result.
But maybe you will be happy with using one of standart views like [SeekBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010019/android-seekbar-minimum-and-continuous-float-value-attributes) or ListView with fast scroll enabled.

Comment: I was thinking on using the seek bar together with an textual indication of the current value while scrolling. Main concern is the sensitivity of the scroll which would be high when having max value = 3900 and thus it would be almost impossible picking the desirable value. One solution could be to have only 40 steps (max = 40) in the seek bar, but then I'm not sure how to expand the bar with lower and higher value ranges..

Comment: Yeah, that is why I said that you need to create custom view )

Comment: Ok, I understand that i need to create custom view. How do you suggest the custom view looks like?

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to read user's mind. )
I'm not a designer, look through other similar apps, try their implementations and make yours.